# How can I check if my program is compiled for 32 or 64 bit processor?

Tags: go

Is there any standard method to check os is 32 or 64 bit?
I've check runtime & os package, but can not found.
http://play.golang.org/p/d6NywMDMcY

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "runtime"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(runtime.GOOS, runtime.GOARCH)
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What do you mean by a 32- or 64-bit OS? For example, `GOARCH=amd64p32`, which is used for `GOOS=nacl`, is `amd64` 64-bit instructions with 32-bit pointers and 32-bit type `int`s and `uint`s.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    const PtrSize = 32 << uintptr(^uintptr(0)>>63)
    fmt.Println(runtime.GOOS, runtime.GOARCH)
    fmt.Println(strconv.IntSize, PtrSize)
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/TKnCA0gqsI

Output:

```
nacl amd64p32
32 32
```

and

```
linux amd64
64 64
```

Comment: I just wish to know IntSize, PtrSize

Comment: @DanielYCLin: if you just want the size of ints and pointers, you can use `unsafe.Sizeof`

Comment: unsafe is not proper. I think strconv is better.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [`unsafe`](http://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Sizeof) package and compute the size of a pointer (4 for 32bits, 8 for 64bits).
Here a working example: http://play.golang.org/p/MPap9KMD1y